# Are there any error notification systems for Java like Hoptoad and Exceptional for Ruby?

Tags: java, logging, hoptoad

There are several excellent hosted services for error notification and processing in the Ruby world, such as [hoptoad](http://hoptoadapp.com/) and [exceptional](http://www.getexceptional.com/).

I'd like to find a similar service for Java.  I don't want to install a separate log monitoring system like [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org/) because this is for a product that gets installed by customers and I need to keep things simple.

I know there's a log4j-to-hoptoad integration called [frog4j](https://github.com/mtah/frog4j), but it hasn't been revved for nearly a year. Are there any other alternatives?  I'd prefer to find a hosted service that supports java directly, or a more actively maintained 3rd party tool.

PS - I'm on Grails if there's something Grails-specific.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I work on [Bugsnag](https://bugsnag.com) and we fully support Java and have an OSS provider for Java which is located on [GitHub](https://github.com/bugsnag/bugsnag-java).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if [this](http://www.jtrac.info/) is what you are looking for but it seems pretty decent.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but JTrac is an issue tracking system, which I already have.  I'm looking for a system that automatically sends server exceptions to a database, then on to me via email.

Comment: Try this link there seems to be a couple that may fit your need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4157769/a-good-database-log-appender-for-java

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LogDigger Connector](http://logdigger.com) library to capture Java web application errors. Standard version is free and collects request-level data and logs. (With Pro version you can track user actions and have the recent usage history included with the error report.)

Notifications can be send via email, collected using RSS or you can implement your own mechanism.

There's a built-in web interface to review error reports so you don't need an external service.